# Layers left off when running python via Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: arcpy, layers, pdf, mapping

My python script generates a number of PDFs from different mxds. If I run the script from Pythonwin everything works great. When I run the script via windows task scheduler it leaves off layers that are turned on and available in the mxd such as street labels. The layers left off the PDF are random, sometimes it even leaves out all but one layer. Has anyone had this issue? Any ideas?

The script I'm running is in my C:\python folder and I have set it to "run when user is logged on or not" with the password saved.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to determine what the problem is without your code and you logging any errors that might be happening.

1. Run the code in the command line. See if any errors pop up in there. The command line and task scheduler should give similar results.
2. If the script requires any files to check, make sure you set the task scheduler to start in the appropriate directory so the files can be seen.
3. If neither of those fix it, add logging to the script, writing out anything that might seem like it is either reading external files, or modifying the map.